# How to detect if any cell is stuck on "Loading..." in the browser, while that same cell already has value via .getValue()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sometimes a cell can get stuck on "Loading...", but it's only in the browser. The value already exists and can be accessible via .getValue() or .getDisplayValue()

Since value exists in the app scripts environment, is it even possible to detect when the browser is stuck?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no Apps Script method that returns the status of the UI, or even a Sheets API method for that matter.

This could even be linked to you internet connection being slow.

As you correctly point out, the values might (or do) already exists in Google servers. The methods you are using to get values go through different network requests as the UI, and thus loading times are unrelated.